# "Unknown MySQL Server" in SQLAlchemy w/ ModWSGI and flask

Tags: mysql, apache, sqlalchemy, mod-wsgi, flask

I'm running a web app on Flask using Sqlalchemy. On the debug server, the app runs fine. But when I try to run it from Apache using ModWSGI (changing none of my code), I suddenly get this error:

> OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'myremotehost.topleveldomain' (111)") None None

What's so mystifying about this is that the mysql server is fine, it's running, and this app can find it when and only when it's running using the flask debugging server. It also finds a MySQL server running locally with no problem.

I'm not even sure what code to show you guys to help, but here's where I call it:

```
engine = create_engine(DATABASE, echo=False) 
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))
```

here's what the url looks like:

> mysql://username:password@mydomain.com:3306/dbname

...and here's the virtualhost code in `httpd.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:808>
    ServerName localhostdomaingoeshere
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/app.wsgi

    Alias /static /path/to/static

    LogLevel info
    ErrorDocument 502 /error

    <Directory /path/to/app>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm sure it's something dumb, I partly just don't even know where to start since the error message doesn't make sense.

Comment: from the host running the webserver, can you connect to the database using the mysql command line client? (`mysql -uusername -p -hmydomain.com dbname`)

Comment: another thing to check.  does the problem go away with `setenforce 0`?

Comment: Hi @TokenMacGuy, thanks for commenting. The mysql server works fine connecting directly (and like I said, the app finds it with no problem when running on the debug server). I also don't have selinux running.

Comment: You say you can connect "directly". Does that mean from an SSH session on the production Apache server? What about a command-line Python script that just does the create_engine() call, again from the web server?

Comment: @jd Yes that's what I meant. The create_engine call works with no errors. I might just switch over to gunicorn.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not really a solution, but I switched over to gunicorn and that's way less of a headache.